# Can GUI elements of a running program be found/located in memory?

Tags: ida, disassembly, windows, debugging, memory

Is it possible for a particular GUI element of a running program (on Windows platform) to be located in memory, such as a text element from a dialog box? For example, locating title text of a drop-down menu or text within an "About" popup box.

Comment: Have You Tried the FindWindow ,EnumWindiws,,getwindowtext functions

Answer (score 1):

There Are Many Apis that can help you locate the pertinent windows
the simplest being FindWindow And GetWindowText
you can run a complete enumeration with EnumWindows using A user provided callback function
these are the for programming part

if you need a readymade option you can look for tools like spy++ that comes with visual studio or many other Gui Spy Programs ( I tend to use winspy++  from catch22.net )

here is a screen shot where I change the About Mozilla Firefox Caption in a live Firefox to some random text

[image]